# In SSMS, what is the number that appears in brackets after the username?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Just out of curiosity, but I notice it changes seemingly at random, and I cannot find any documentation online for it at all. I have tried Googling it, and I fear I am poorly wording my search terms to find it.

I'm trying to workout what the numbers in brackets are after the username that is executing a query in SSMS are or for?

In the tab name or the window title, it'll appear like this:

```
SQLQuery19.sql - server_name.db_name (NETWORK\user (525))
```

The number seemingly changes when I open a new query at different times, and it doesn't seem to increase or decrease with any sort of pattern. Any links to documentation or brief explanation would be great.

Comment: If you right-click the server, and open Activity Monitor, you can see the session id there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the `session_id` - you can confirm by running `SELECT @@SPID;` in that window.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/spid-transact-sql